# Django background 404. Feel URL configuration error

Tags: python, django-urls

This is my view
[image]

This is my URL configuration
[image]

Why visit background 404？？？？？？
[image]
How should URL be configured？？？？？？？

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

You specify your URLs with the [**`path(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#django.urls.path), this does not work with regular expressions: you can specify these as regular expressions with [**`re_path(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#django.urls.re_path)

You can rewrite the paths to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('books/', views.BookAPIView.as_view()),
    path('books/<int:book_id>/', views.BookDetailInfoView.as_view())
]
```